# Are there applications of this result?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $E$ a ($\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$)-space vector (where char($\mathbb{K})\neq 2$).
> Let $f\in \mathcal{L}(E)$ such that $f^2 = 0$.
>
> $Im(f) = \ker(f)$ **iff** there exists $g \in \mathcal{L}(E)$ such
> that : $f\circ g +  g\circ f = Id_E$.

Are there concrete or abstract applications of this property ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why is there a downvote ?